# Compile time error "final variable is not initialized"

Tags: java, constructor, final

I have an issue, while trying few code snippets i came across a code

```
class O
{
    final int i;
    O()
    {
        i=10;
    }
    O(int j)// error here as THE BLANK FINAL FIELD i IS NOT INITIALIZED
    {
        j=20;
        System.out.println(j);
    }
}
class Manager3
{
    public static void main(final String[] args) 
    {
        O n1=new O();
        //O n2=new O(10);
        //n1.i=20;
        //System.out.println(j1.i);
    }
}
```

but if i comment the constructor with parameter i do not get any errors.

My question is why am i getting this compile time error when i put both the constructor in code and why i dont get any error when i remove parameterized constructor.

I know that we have to initialize my final variable, but i am initializing it in constructor thus if i write this code :-

```
class O
{
    final int i;
    O()
    {
        i=10;
    }

}
class Manager3
{
    public static void main(final String[] args) 
    {
        O n1=new O();

    }
}
```

every this is working fine and code is compiling.

My question is what is the issue if i introduce another constructor. Even the error is at the line where i write parameterized cons.

I have understanding of JAVA but i am confused in this code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
final int i;
```

You have defined `i` as `final`. You can assign values to final variables only in constructors.

```
 O(int j)// error here as THE BLANK FINAL FIELD i IS NOT INITIALIZED
    {
        j=20;
        System.out.println(j);
    }
```

Here you are not assigning value for `i`. If someone uses this constructor (constructor with parameter) to create an object, `i` value won't be assigned.

**How to resolve this?**

As you said, either you have to comment this constructor (or) assign `i` value inside this constructor as you did in other constructor.

Comment: You are right, the real answer i was expecting was, "i" is a class variable thus i need to initialize it in each and every constructor i define.

Comment: @Ali: 1) i is instance variable, not class variable. 2) All instance variables don't need to be assigned in constructor unless they are final and NOT assigned to a value already.

Comment: @Ali: If you remove final from i declaration, you don't get compiler error. If your intention is test SO people, sure you are going to get very nice answers.

Comment: @Nimbari, no my intention was not to test SO people, but i was really confused, and i know the solution but was not aware of that the final variables are to be initialized either when we are defining them or in every constructor of that class.

Answer (score 3):

```
   O(int j){
        this(); // <----- you can add this line. 
        j=20;
        System.out.println(j);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

A `final` variable has to be initialized on declaration or assigned to a value in the **constructors body**.
If you don't initialize the `final` variable you get a compiler error.

If you invoke the second constructor the variable never gets assigned to a value.

Answer (score 0):

"i" is a instance final variable thus we need to initialize it in each and every constructor i define.