# Spring Error:(21, 34) java: variable customUriBuilder not initialized in the default constructor

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have Spring bean

```
@Component
public class CustomUriBuilder {

    private final String cUrl;
    private final String redirectUri;
    private final String clientId;

    public CustomUriBuilder (@Value("${project.url}") String cUrl,
                          @Value("${project.redirect.url}") String redirectUri, @Value("${project.client-id}") String clientId) {
        this.cUrl= cUrl;
        this.redirectUri = redirectUri;
        this.clientId = clientId;
    }
    //No default constructor
}
```

I need to inject this bean in another bean

```
@Component
public class LinksBuilder {
    @Autowired
    private final CustomUriBuilder customUriBuilder ;
    //No constructors
}
```

But i got compilation error

> Error:(21, 34) java: variable customUriBuilder not initialized in the
>   default constructor

At the same time i am injecting `LinksBuilder`(as final)  in another controller without any problems

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(produces = "application/json")
public class resourceV4 {

    private final LinksBuilder linksBuilder;
    //No constructors 
    .
}
```

Why in the first case it gives an error but in the second case it is working fine?

Comment: Either `@Autowire` the property through the constructor or make it not `final`. This is btw not a Spring-problem, but a java-issue since final fields must be initialized.

Comment: @Turing85,it works, but I injected other final beans without any issues, Why i should make this one not final ?

Comment: As I said: you have to initialize final variables. This is nothing spring-specific, but is specified in the JLS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compile time error "final variable is not initialized"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13052571/compile-time-error-final-variable-is-not-initialized)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since spring 4.3 there is a feature - you can not add `Autowired` annotation for the final fields injection

You must have a constructor initialization for the final fields. I can not see one for the LinksBuilder and resourceV4. See lombok `@RequiredArgsContructor` for short.

It is impossible that one class with a final field is compiled ok and without constructor, but another one with an error.

Run other compilers or build ways (terminal gradlew/maven etc) to clarify the situation for you

Comment: You are absolutely right, we are using lombok, and I forgot to add @RequiredArgsContructor on LinksBuilder